# Ignoring a specific letter grade when calculating average student grade

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the average of the numeric grade for students who take [0]=14224. But how do I tell my program to ignore any grades with a 'W'?

```
import sys
import csv


def findnumericgrade(grade):
    if grade == 'A':
        return 4.0
    elif grade == 'B':
        return 3.0
    else:
        return 2.0


def loaddata(filename, course):
    count = 0
    total = 0.0
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = csv.reader(f)
        next(lines)
        for row in lines:
            if course in row[0]:
                get_grade = findnumericgrade(row[3])
                total += float(get_grade)
                count += 1
        avg = total / count
    print(f"The {course} average is: {round(avg, 2)}")


loaddata('studentdata.csv', sys.argv[1])
```

#example of studentdata.csv:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certainly a number of ways. The easiest approach is probably just to check for the 'W' string and continue to the next row.

One approach to doing this is to use the [continue](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) control to move on to the next iteration in the loop.

```py
def loaddata(filename, course):
    count = 0
    total = 0.0
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = csv.reader(f)
        next(lines)
        for row in lines:
            if row[3] == 'W':
                continue  # Go to next iteration in loop
            if course in row[0]:
                get_grade = findnumericgrade(row[3])
                total += float(get_grade)
                count += 1
        avg = total / count
    print(f"The {course} average is: {round(avg, 2)}")
```

---

You can also do this by making your if statement the `and` [boolean operation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=boolean#boolean-operations) to also ensure that Course_Grade is not 'W'.

```py
def loaddata(filename, course):
    count = 0
    total = 0.0
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = csv.reader(f)
        next(lines)
        for row in lines:
            if course in row[0] and row[3] != 'W':
                get_grade = findnumericgrade(row[3])
                total += float(get_grade)
                count += 1
        avg = total / count
    print(f"The {course} average is: {round(avg, 2)}")
```

---

The above solutions are probably most practical, since this looks like some sort of utility script, but depending on how large you expect your dataset to be, you could use something like [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Then you'd have access to all of the data manipulation and analysis tools it offers.

```py
import sys
import pandas as pd


def find_numeric_grade(grade):
    if grade == 'A':
        return 4.0
    elif grade == 'B':
        return 3.0
    else:
        return 2.0


df = pd.read_csv('studentdata.csv')
section_number = int(sys.argv[1])

print(df[(section_number == df['Section_Number']) & (df['Course_Grade'] != 'W')]
      ['Course_Grade'].apply(find_numeric_grade).mean())
```

*Solutions tested with the following data in **studentdata.csv**

```
Section_Number,Prof_ID,Student_ID,Course_Grade,Student_Name,Course_ID
14224,5,109,B,John Smith,IT1130
14224,5,110,B,Jennifer Johnson,IT1130
14224,5,111,W,Kristen Hawkins,IT1130
14224,5,112,A,Tom Brady,IT1130
14224,5,113,C,Cam Newton,IT1130
14224,5,114,C,Tim Tebow,IT1130
14225,5,115,A,Peyton Manning,IT1130
14225,5,116,B,Maria Sharapova,IT1130
14225,5,117,W,Brian McCoy,IT1130
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if course in row[0]:
     if row[3]!='W':
          get_grade = findnumericgrade(row[3])
          total += float(get_grade)
          count += 1
      avg = total / count
```